# Translateservice is not working in two pages in Ionic3?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

Hello there am trying to develop language translation using i18n in Ionic 3. For this i used `ngx-translate` service. it is works in single page only but not working in multiple pages Can you please help me out from this?

Thansk & Regards

I have a json files in assests/i18n/ folder with names of `es.json, en.json, hin.json.`

I have wrote below code for test page also but it is shows an error message called

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'translate' could not be found ("
    </ion-list>

    <p>{{[ERROR ->]'HELLO WORLD!' | translate}}</p>

    <ion-item>
"):
```

Please give me a solution for this.

Here is the some part of HTML Code :

```
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
.
.
.
.

<ion-content padding>  
   <ion-list inset class="no-border">
      <ion-item>
         <ion-label>{{'HELLO WORLD!' | translate}}</ion-label>
         <ion-input required type="text"></ion-input>
      </ion-item> 
   </ion-list>
   <p>{{'HELLO WORLD!' | translate}}</p>
   <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Select Language</ion-label>
      <ion-select #l (ionChange)="languagefilter(l.value);">
         <ion-option value="en">English</ion-option>
         <ion-option value="es">Spanish</ion-option>
         <ion-option value="hin" (click)="new()">Hindi</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
   </ion-item>
   <button ion-button (click)="chainaddition()">Login</button>
</ion-content>
```

Here is the TS code

```
 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public translate: TranslateService) {
    let temp = localStorage.getItem("language");
    if(temp=='en'){
      translate.setDefaultLang('en');
      alert("English")
    } else {
      translate.setDefaultLang(temp);
      localStorage.removeItem("temp");
      // alert(this.alertmessage);
    }
  }
  languagefilter(value) {
    localStorage.setItem("language", value);
    location.reload();
   }
  chainaddition() {
    this.navCtrl.push("TestPage");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`translate` pipe is part of `TranslateModule`. Unlike services, `component`, `directive` and `pipe` are not global. You need to import the module of a pipe you want to use.

You need to import `TranslateModule` (do not call `forRoot` function) in every module or you can create a `SharedModule` and import this `SharedModule` everywhere else as it is mentioned in the [docs](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#sharedmodule)

> If you use a SharedModule that you import in multiple other feature modules, you can export the TranslateModule to make sure you don't have to import it in every module.

```js
@NgModule({
    exports: [
        CommonModule,
        TranslateModule
    ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

> Note: Never call a forRoot static method in the SharedModule. You
>   might end up with different instances of the service in your injector
>   tree. But you can use forChild if necessary.